# How to use Gradle to generate JavaDoc in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, javadoc

I can not find any documentation on how to configure my Gradle file to create the JavaDoc for my project. I already tried some snippets from SO and blog articles but none of them seem to work or they do not provide context.

This is my Gradle file. What do I need to do to add a task to generate JavaDoc?

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In our projects we added the following to the app's `build.gradle`:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
    description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
    source = variant.javaCompile.source
    ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
    classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)
    options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
    options.links("http://d.android.com/reference/");
  }
}
```

This will add tasks to the build of the form `generate<build_variant>Javadoc`. So let's say you have a `free` and a `pro` version of your app, this would add tasks like:

```
generateFreeDebugJavadoc
generateFreeReleaseJavadoc
generateProDebugJavadoc
generateProReleaseJavadoc
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i get a weird error trying this : `Error:(77, 0) Could not find property 'applicationVariants' on com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension_Decorated@19be5795.` - any thoughts?

Comment: 2 things - 1. The ``applicationVariants`` only works for the app plugin, i.e., if you're building a library it would be ``libraryVariants``. 2. Check your android gradle plugin version. It might be that it's not up to date or it's too recent and this changed as well.

Comment: When running this initially, I got errors regarding the R.** files.  Added the following "exclude '**/BuildConfig.java" and "exclude '**/R.java'" right after the class path.

Answer (score 2):

In android studio, write a gradle task of type Javadoc :

```
 task createJavadocs (type: Javadoc)
  {
        source = project.android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        options.linkSource true
        classpath += project.files(project.android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
        failOnError false
  }
```

Simply execute this task will create javadocs.